# Apigee response not getting sent to angular application

Tags: apigee

I have an angular that sends calls to Apigee. After tracing the calls i can see that a response is returned. However the client does not get the response. I have no idea what i could be missing in this instance.

I have set up CORS correctly on Apigee and can see the options preflight response getting called successfully. The issue really is on the second call, a response is returned but the client receives null data

Answer (score 0):

Well, working with the description you've sent, what you could do:

1. Debug the API call using the Chrome Developer tools: use ctrl-shift-J and then choose the 'network' tab. See if the clal is coming in. Clicking on the specific API call shows you the response
2. also maybe check the console that is shown when using above command (crl-shift-J)
3. indeed check the Apigee trace. But if the trace shows a reply is sent, then probably it is.
4. add some console.log in the Angular application or try to debug it so that you are certain it's an Angular issue.

maybe share some code so that we can better help you.